# How do I change the "secure" and "httpOnly" attributes of the cookies provided by the EU Cookie Compliance module?

Tags: 9, cookies

I am using the eu cookie compliance module in Drupal 9 and I need to change the "secure" and "httpOnly" values of the cookies, as I am getting a vulnerability error "CWE-614: Sensitive Cookie in HTTPS Session Without 'Secure' Attribute".
I have tested from the settings.php using the following code:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);
```

However it didn't work, I also tried with some modules but it didn't work either.
[image]

Comment: What is the Drupal version? What module produces those cookies?

Comment: I am using drupal 9

Comment: Which module produces those cookies? You did not say that in the question. I am downvoting the question until you add that information.

Comment: I am using the eu cookie compliance module

Comment: Please add that information to the Question. Also, for what it's worth, those are not PHP session cookies so `ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1)` will not do anything to change these cookies..

Comment: Oh okay I understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking over the 8.x-1.x branch of that module, what you are asking seems to be unsupported there. It sets cookies like:

```
cookies.set(cookieName, status, { path: path, domain: domain, sameSite: 'strict' });
```

However, `cookies.set` [supports all the possible options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/set).

So the answer to this question is: Open a feature request with the module maintainers, or patch the files in the `js` directory, or both.

Comment: wow thank you very much my friend

Comment: Please accept the answer.